# hide or disable or prevent pull down status bar (notification bar) inside Service while the service is running

Tags: android, service, hide, statusbar

I am writing a launcher for kids. Parents can switch between their Launcher and kids Launcher.
i need to hide status bar (notification bar) while its in kids Launcher, even when the kids use the applications which parents put in kids launcher.

the code below works fine when I put it in `onCreate` of my each activity.

```
this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

but as i do not have access to `onCreate` those applications which added to kids Launcher, i am not able to hide it in these cases.
what I want to do is running a background `service` during the device is in kids Launcher and from that `service` hide or disable `status bar`.

it will also be a good way to prevent `status bar` pull down inside my `service`

is there any suggestion to disable `status bar` in a `service`.

The picture below shows the way that Samsung kids Launcher handled it, after user goes to kids Launcher , in the `status bar` shows an icon and the user is not able to pull down the `status bar`

[image]

Comment: hello, have u find solution for this? if yes please help me i have same issue